# ejecuto con el movil me sale INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

Estoy probando una aplicacion en el movil para gestionar mi almacen. El programa esta funcionando correctamente en un periferico virtual del AVD manager del propio android studio, pero hoy queria mirar como se veria en mi movil. Es un HUAWEI P9 LITE. con version de android 7.0

cuando le doy a ejecutar la aplicacion en mi movil desde AVD manager de android estudio me aparece este error:

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED
```

He mirado el manifest pero no me da ningun error en android studio , de hecho tengo el check verde.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="Alastor.Ova">
    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup">
        <activity android:name=".Buscar_Entradadotacion" />
        <activity android:name=".Entradadotacion_DotacionActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Dotacion" />
        <activity android:name=".Eliminarrepuesto_salidamaterialactivity" />
        <activity android:name=".BuscarrepuestoSalidamaterialactivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Crearrepuesto_Salidamaterialactivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Eliminarrepuesto_Entradamaterialactivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Buscarrespuesto_Entradamaterialactivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Crearentradamaterial_Entradamaterialactivity" />
        <activity android:name=".EntradaMaterial" />
        <activity android:name=".SalidaMaterial" />
        <activity android:name=".EliminarRespuestoAlmacenActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".BuscarrespuestoAlmacenActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".EditarRepuestoAlmacenAcitivity" />
        <activity android:name=".CrearRepuestoAlmacenActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".AlmacenActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

He mirado información tanto por aquí como por otras paginas pero no he encontrado nada que parezca estar mal.

Edit: he estado mirando mas las pantalla de errores me pone esto

```18:28    Failed to commit install session 691237953 with command cmd package install-commit 691237953. Error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl691237953.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #20):  does not have valid android:name````

sin embargo he quitado ese nombre, lo he vuelto a poner y me sigue dando el mismo fallo , android me reconoce la actividad cuando la estoy tecleando, incluso le doy al tab para que lo autorellene.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Realizaste cambio de "package name"? algún cambio en tu AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Si haciendo uno nuevo me hizo uno en example, pero lo borre y lo configure todo para que todos entraran en Alastor.Ova. en el gradle seccion -> build.grade -> default config ->applicationId-> tengo puesto Alastor.Ova. Igual hay alguna forma de asegurarme.

Comment: Ese pudo ser el problema pero cambia el paquete a minúsculas, tanto en el manifest.xml como en el build.gradle .

Comment: lo cambie en las carpetas donde estaba guardado todo el proyecto desde android studio , luego cambie en el manifest y en el build.gralde y ya funciona muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He visto un detalle en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` y es el nombre del paquete lo cual puede ocasionar el error:

> The application could not be installed:
> INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

Cambia el paquete de:

```
 package="Alastor.Ova"
```

hacia todo en minúsculas:

```
 package="alastor.ova"
```

este cambio también realizalo en tu `build.gradle`:

```
  applicationId "alastor.ova"
```

Te sugiero que también físicamente cambies el nombre en los directorios a minusculas.

Comment: ha funcionado muchas gracias he hecho lo que me has comentado y he cambiado los nombres también de las carpetas y funciono .

Comment: Excelente @AlastorOvanTD , saludos!